# Why aren't ILogger.LogTrace messages displayed in the console window for func.exe for a v2 Azure Function App

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-functions

With recent changes to the Azure Function App version 2 in Sept 2018, my function app code was refactored.  However, it seems that:

- LogTrace() messages no longer show in the console window (and I suspect Application Insights), and
- *categoryLevels* in host.json does not seem to be respected.

The issue was duplicated in a *sample* application below in the call to *LogWithILogger()*.   Two other points:

(1) I note that the default filter trace level seems to be hard-coded.  Could another Filter be added to allow LogTrace() to work, or should LogTrace() no longer be used?  If another Filter can be added, how does one inject the necessary objects into the Function App to permit that?

```
public static void Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AddDefaultWebJobsFilter(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
{
    builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.None);
    builder.AddFilter((c,l) => Filter(c, l, LogLevel.Information));
}
```

(2) The Intellisense around LogLevel indicates:

- LogLevel.Trace = 0

*Logs that contain the most detailed messages.  These messages may contain sensitive application data. These messages are disabled by default and should never be enabled in a production environment.*

I would expect that LogTrace could be used for the console window when debugging - and would be controlled by the categoryLevel settings.

So, what should one be doing in terms of writing trace messages for a V2 Function app using ILogger?  Thanks for the advice!

**SAMPLE APPLICATION**

**Function1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Description;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace FunctionAppTestLogging
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    [Binding]
    public class InjectAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public InjectAttribute(Type type)
        {
            Type = type;
        }
        public Type Type { get; }
    }

    public class WebJobsExtensionStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder webjobsBuilder)
        {

            webjobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging(builder => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace).AddFilter("Function", LogLevel.Trace));
            ServiceCollection serviceCollection =  (ServiceCollection) webjobsBuilder.Services;
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = webjobsBuilder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // webjobsBuilder.Services.AddLogging();
            //  webjobsBuilder.Services.AddSingleton(new LoggerFactory());
            // loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(serviceProvider, Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
        }
    }

    public static class Function1
    {
        private static string _configuredLoggingLevel;

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context) // , [Inject(typeof(ILoggerFactory))] ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) //  , [Inject(typeof(ILoggingBuilder))] ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
        {
            LogWithILogger(log);
            LogWithSeriLog();
            SetupLocalLoggingConfiguration(context, log);
            LogWithWrappedILogger(log);

            return await RunStandardFunctionCode(req);
        }

        private static void SetupLocalLoggingConfiguration(ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                            .Build();

            // Access AppSettings when debugging locally.
            string loggingLevel = config["LoggingLevel"];  // This needs to be set in the Azure Application Settings for it to work in the cloud.
            _configuredLoggingLevel = loggingLevel;
        }

        private static void LogWithWrappedILogger(ILogger log)
        {
            LogWithWrappedILoggerHelper("This is Critical information from WrappedILogger", LogLevel.Critical, log);
            LogWithWrappedILoggerHelper("This is Error information from WrappedILogger", LogLevel.Error, log);
            LogWithWrappedILoggerHelper("This is Information information from WrappedILogger", LogLevel.Information, log);
            LogWithWrappedILoggerHelper("This is Debug information from WrappedILogger", LogLevel.Debug, log);
            LogWithWrappedILoggerHelper("This is TRACE information from WrappedILogger", LogLevel.Trace, log);
        }

        private static void LogWithWrappedILoggerHelper(string message, LogLevel messageLogLevel, ILogger log)
        {
            // This works as expected - Is the host.json logger section not being respected?
            Enum.TryParse(_configuredLoggingLevel, out LogLevel logLevel);
            if (messageLogLevel >= logLevel)
            {
                log.LogInformation(message);
            }
        }

        private static void LogWithILogger(ILogger log)
        {
            var logger = log;
            // Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger _logger = logger; // Logger is protected - so not accessible.

            log.LogCritical("This is critical information!!!");
            log.LogDebug("This is debug information!!!");
            log.LogError("This is error information!!!");
            log.LogInformation("This is information!!!");
            log.LogWarning("This is warning information!!!");

            log.LogTrace("This is TRACE information!! from LogTrace");
            log.Log(LogLevel.Trace, "This is TRACE information from Log", null);
        }

        private static void LogWithSeriLog()
        {
            // Code using the Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage package per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/logging?tabs=csharp
            /*
            var serilog = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.AzureTableStorage(connectionString, storageTableName: tableName, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
            .CreateLogger();
            log.Debug("Here is a debug message {message}", "with some structured content");
            log.Verbose("Here is a verbose log message");
            log.Warning("Here is a warning log message");
            log.Error("Here is an error log message");
            */
        }

        private static async Task<IActionResult> RunStandardFunctionCode(HttpRequest req)
        {
            string name = req.Query["name"];
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }
}
```

**host.json**

```
  {
  "version": "2.0",
  // The Azure Function App DOES appear to read from host.json even when debugging locally thru VS, since it complains if you do not use a valid level.
  "logger": {
    "categoryFilter": {
      "defaultLevel": "Trace", // Trace, Information, Error
      "categoryLevels": {
        "Function": "Trace"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For v2 function, [log setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#logging) in `host.json` has a different format.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      // For specific function
      "Function.Function1": "Trace",
      // For all functions
      "Function":"Trace",
      // Default settings, e.g. for host 
      "default": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```